# How can I reset administrator password on Server 2003 that's running in VMWare on a Mac?

Tags: passwords, windows-server-2003

I've got a virtual machine for Windows Server 2003 Enterprise Edition that I don't know the password for. It's running on VMWare for Mac.

Any ideas how to reset/retrieve the password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had success using Ophcrack:

http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/

It has a live CD that you can boot from.

Answer (score 0):

Download a copy of the [TRK](http://trinityhome.org/Home/index.php?wpid=1&front_id=12) iso, boot it and then use the password reset program 'winpass' and that should do it. There are many other methods but I think that is the fastest way I can think of.